# Overriding a vendor file in Laravel Framework 7.29.3

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to override a vendor file located at "vendor\cimpleo\omnipay-authorizenetrecurring\src\Objects\Schedule.php" to correct some issues.

```
composer.json

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Cimpleo\\": "app/Overrides/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories",
            "vendor/google/apiclient/src",
            "vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": ["vendor\\cimpleo\\omnipay-authorizenetrecurring\\src\\Objects\\Schedule.php"]
    }
```

Then I copied and edited the Schedule.php to folder `"app\Overrides"`.

```
namespace Cimpleo;

use Academe\AuthorizeNet\PaymentInterface;
use Academe\AuthorizeNet\AbstractModel;
use Omnipay\Common\Exception\InvalidRequestException;
use DateTime;

class Schedule extends AbstractModel
{
...
```

The vendor Schedule.php file looks like this.

```
namespace Omnipay\AuthorizeNetRecurring\Objects;

use Academe\AuthorizeNet\PaymentInterface;
use Academe\AuthorizeNet\AbstractModel;
use Omnipay\Common\Exception\InvalidRequestException;
use DateTime;

class Schedule extends AbstractModel
{

    const SCHEDULE_UNIT_DAYS = 'days';
    const SCHEDULE_UNIT_MONTHS = 'months';

    protected $intervalLength;
    protected $intervalUnit;
    protected $startDate;
    protected $totalOccurrences;
    protected $trialOccurrences;

    public function __construct($parameters = null) {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->setIntervalLength($parameters['intervalLength']);
        $this->setIntervalUnit($parameters['intervalUnit']);
        $this->setStartDate($parameters['startDate']);
        $this->setTotalOccurrences($parameters['totalOccurrences']);
        if (isset($parameters['trialOccurrences'])) {
            $this->setTrialOccurrences($parameters['trialOccurrences']);
        }
    }

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        $data = [];
        if ($this->hasIntervalLength()) {
            $data['interval']['length'] = $this->getIntervalLength();
        }
        if ($this->hasIntervalUnit()) {
            $data['interval']['unit'] = $this->getIntervalUnit();
        }
        if ($this->hasStartDate()) {
            $data['startDate'] = $this->getStartDate();
        }
        if ($this->hasTotalOccurrences()) {
            $data['totalOccurrences'] = $this->getTotalOccurrences();
        }
        if ($this->hasTrialOccurrences()) {
            $data['trialOccurrences'] = $this->getTrialOccurrences();
        }
        return $data;
    }
    
    protected function setIntervalLength(int $value) {
        if ($value < 7 || $value > 365) {
            throw new InvalidRequestException('Interval Length must be a string, between "7" and "365".');
        }
        $this->intervalLength = (string)$value;
    }
...
```

The class is instantiated here

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Omnipay\Omnipay;
use Omnipay\AuthorizeNetRecurring;
use Omnipay\AuthorizeNetRecurring\Objects\Schedule;
use Omnipay\Common\CreditCard;

class AuthorizeNetRecurringController extends Controller
{
    private $gateway;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->gateway = Omnipay::create('AuthorizeNetRecurring_Recurring');

        $this->gateway->setAuthName('3KJZb44jR');
        $this->gateway->setTransactionKey('2fFqRA7w22a2G7He');
        $this->gateway->setTestMode(true);
    }

    //
    public function createSubscription(Request $request) {

        $schedule = new Schedule([
            //For a unit of days, use an integer between 7 and 365, inclusive. For a unit of months, use an integer between 1 and 12, inclusive.
            'intervalLength' => '1',
            // use values 'days' or 'months'
            'intervalUnit' => 'months',
            //date in format 'YYYY-mm-dd'
            'startDate' => date("Y-m-d"), //'2020-03-10',
            //To create an ongoing subscription without an end date, set totalOccurrences to "9999".
            'totalOccurrences' => '12',
            //If a trial period is specified, include the number of payments during the trial period in totalOccurrences.
            'trialOccurrences' => '1',
        ]);
...
```

Then run `composer dump-autoload`. After running the script the app is still calling the vendor file that causes the error below. Composer changes doesn't seem to work.

```
Omnipay\Common\Exception\InvalidRequestException
Interval Length must be a string, between "7" and "365".
Omnipay\AuthorizeNetRecurring\Objects\Schedule::setIntervalLength
D:\xampp\htdocs\SBF_app_version1.5\vendor\cimpleo\omnipay-authorizenetrecurring\src\Objects\Schedule.php:56
```

Thanks

Comment: You're telling composer to look for the `Cimpleo` namespace in the `app/Overrides` directory, but then you're putting the `App\Overrides` namespace in there instead. Also your `exclude-from-classmap` has a bunch of backslashes in it. Might be helpful to show how you're instantiating this object as well.

Comment: Thanks  miken32, appreciate your thoughts. What would be the correct autoload setting for this?

Comment: Why not fork that library and override the dependency properly?

Comment: I don't think you can do this, each dependency will provide its own composer.json file specifying what it will enter in your autoloader. `exclude-from-classmap` probably won't work if the package doesn't use a classmap so either make a fork of the project, fix the issue there and then do a pull request (and hope a maintainer accepts it and releases a new version) or even publish your own release (since the library you're dealing with seems abandoned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to import the overridden class, instead of the original one.

```
use Cimpleo\Schedule;
// use Omnipay\AuthorizeNetRecurring\Objects\Schedule;
```

But a better solution to this problem would be to use inheritance:

```
namespace App\Overrides\Cimpleo;

use Omnipay\AuthorizeNetRecurring\Objects\Schedule as BaseSchedule;

class Schedule extends BaseSchedule
{
    ...
}
```

And then in the controller you would import the new `Schedule` class:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Omnipay\Omnipay;
use Omnipay\AuthorizeNetRecurring;
use App\Overrides\Cimpleo\Schedule;
use Omnipay\Common\CreditCard;

class AuthorizeNetRecurringController extends Controller
{
    ...
}
```

Also you would have to remove the new autoloading instruction and also `exclude-from-classmap` in composer. Just autoload `app` directory and it would be enough:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
```

Comment: I think you have to import the overridden class, instead of the original one. use Cimpleo\Schedule; // use Omnipay\AuthorizeNetRecurring\Objects\Schedule; haha rookie mistake on my part. Thanks Pedram Behroozi for pointing this out much appreciated and I'll try your best sol'n too and to miken32 and others too for some advice. God bless!